# How calculate printer average-toner-coverage used per page using SNMP

Tags: linux, networking, snmp, printer, snmpd

I want to know the rage toner used per page, for example:
for one page print was used x toner 
for other page print was uses 2X toner

I suppose are some SNMP mibs/oids  to do this;

some idea ?

Answer (score 0):

What you can usually get is the number of pages you printed with a toner cartridge and in some cases an average toner coverage in % of the page covered (on the B/W model I had this statistic, this pretty universally ended up with 5.0% coverage). These counters alone give you a pretty decent value for the average price of a printed page.

I've never seen stats regarding min and max values in the printer, this kind of analysis would have to be done by print server software that calculates these values before sending the job off to the printer.

Comment: What I need is to know is the average toner used after I print a page compared with a standard , or the percent(area, square) of the page when the printer effectively used toner. Ex.: When I print a page I can print only on halp on it , or I can print full on all page. How IO can know this info?(printer square footage ) I am filing somehow this OIDS can be used : prtMarkerSuppliesGroup prtMarkerCounterUnit prtMarkerLifeCount prtMediaPathMedia prtInputMediaWeight

But I don't know how to deal with them
 how software do it?